# javascript document.write variables

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm writing a simple javascript with several document.write statements...

```
String accountLink = "#";
String accountLogo = "img/myLogos/someLogo.png";

function drawLogos(){
    document.write('<li><a href="');
    document.write("#");  // link to account page
    document.write('"><img src="');
    document.write('img/myLogos/someLogoF.png'); // reference to logo image
    document.write('" alt=""  /></a></li>');
}
```

Which works just fine. but when I use a variable like this...

```
document.write(accountLink);
```

it doesn't load anything. I've tried getting rid of the quotes but nothing different happens. Is there some small syntax error I'm not picking up on?

Comment: `Java` is not `javascript`. `javascript` is not `Java`.

Comment: Check your Javascript console, you're getting syntax errors on the lines that begin with `String`.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't load anything"?

Comment: Why are you leading your `accountLink` and `accountLogo` with `String`, there are no `String`s in JavaScript, only `Objects`. Use `var` instead.

Comment: when I run it it is as if the write functions aren't executing. as if they weren't there at all. at least that's why I see when I load the web page.

Comment: got it fixed. var instead of String, who knew #everybody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
var accountLink = "#";
var accountLogo = "img/myLogos/someLogo.png";
```

Comment: dough! do feel like a putz or what!

Comment: also don't use document.write. Try document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(accountLogo);

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize variable instead of `String` using `var` and then try:

```
var mytext = "Hello again";
document.write(mytext);
```

[Here is working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kE7Gj/)

Answer (score 1):

Declare your string variables with var

```
  var accountLink = "#";
document.write(accountLink);
```

Comment: Yeah, I got that right after I submitted the question. I'm so use to just java

Comment: I heard that.. Its nice to be quick and dirty... until u need data types ;)

Answer (score 1):

use `var` instead of String, Javascript is a weak typing language

```
<script>
        var accountLink = "#";
        var accountLogo = "img/myLogos/someLogo.png";

        function drawLogos(){
            document.write('<li><a href="');
            document.write(accountLink);  // link to account page
            document.write('"><img src="');
            document.write(accountLogo); // reference to logo image
            document.write('" alt=""  /></a></li>');
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I know. silly question now that I think about it. too use to writing string :P

Comment: people used to strong type languages, always have problems like this with weak type languages